# Applescript refer a link to a file in current finder window

Tags: finder, applescript, dialog

Edited.

Where is my current script :

```
set plistfile_path to POSIX file "/users/moi/Desktop/Time/"

choose file with prompt "Please choose a file:" of type {"plist"} ¬
    default location plistfile_path


##set the plistfile_path to "~/Desktop/myTime.plist"
tell application "System Events"
    set p_list to property list file (plistfile_path)
    -- read the plist data
    set startTimeValue to value of property list item "startTime" of p_list
end tell
```

I don't manage to get it work using the choose file dialog.

I'm having this error :

```
"error "System Events got an error: Can’t make file \"Macintosh HD:Users:nadjarian:Desktop:Time:\" into type integer." number -1700 from file "Macintosh HD:Users:moi:Desktop:Time:" to integer
"
```

if I get script of the dialog, it's work fine with this list instead :

```
set the plistfile_path to "~/Desktop/myTime.plist"
```

any idea how to fix the error?

Comment: You can just get the result of a `choose file` dialog or the Finder’s `selection` and coerce it to a string.  The name in your example is already dynamic - what are you trying to accomplish with the property list?

Comment: sorry I didn't right my original post very well, I just did an edit.

Comment: Is your original topic title still relevant?  In your new script you aren’t doing anything with the file choice - it should be something like `set plistfile_path to (choose file with prompt “whatever”) as text` (note the coercion to text for use with `property list file`).

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work for me,

I'm setting the patch with the variable P and set a to POSIX file p

Then I create a dialog with the default location of the variable A

```
set p to "/Users/usernmaHere/Desktop/Time"
set a to POSIX file p


set config_file to choose file with prompt "Locate your .plist config file and click OK" of type "plist" default location a
```

I added file limitation with " type "plist"

Comment: An answer should explain what it is doing